# Python, can I make a single if statement rather than a dozen if drawing from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

Using Python:
Hello, I am wondering if I am able to make a single statement rather than a dozen if/elif statements. My dictionary has 12 weapons with key values from 1-12. I imagine there must be a way to make a statement similar to 'if selection is 1-12, then print "You have chosen [the correct dictionary value]. Below is my current first if statement:

```
weapons = {
        1: "Dagger",
        2: "Long Sword",
        3: "Bastard Sword"
    }
print("\nWhat type of weapon do you use?")
print("Please choose from the following:\n")
    for key, value in weapons.items():
        print(key, ":", value)
    try:
        selection = int(input("\nSelect a number: "))
        if selection == 1:
            print("You have chosen the " + weapons[1] + "\n")
            print("You have chosen, wisely.")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your weapons and their IDs are stored in a dictionary. Think about how a dictionary is useful. How do you usually access _specific_ dictionary values? Then look at these two code snippets: `selection == 1`  /  `weapons[1]` - something is the same between them. What is it?

Comment: In fact, it appears you already know how to look up the value, because the code already does it: `weapons[1]`. So - what exactly is the difficulty? Why do you think the code should need multiple `if` statements? What *problem do you hope to solve* by having them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if selection is in the dictionary

```
if selection in weapons:
    ...
```

Or, since you have a try/except block anyway, catch the `KeyError` on failure. Here, using an f-string, python will attempt to get `weapons[selection]` and will raise `KeyError` if its not there. Similarly, on bad input that cannot be converted to `int`, python will raise `ValueError`. One try/except catches both errors.

```
try:
    selection = int(input("\nSelect a number: "))
    print(f"You have chosen the {weapons[selection]}")
    print("You have chosen, wisely.")
except (KeyErrror, ValueError):
    print(f"Selection '{selection}' is not valid")
```

Comment: Ah, you eventually came to the same conclusion as I did about *what the actual question is*. In this case, of course, it is a common duplicate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Considering the structure of the example, I thought it best answer the exact question (use `in`) but also highlight how one can leverage exception handling. Since this covers both the dictionary lookup and the `input` conversion, I think this answer is still valuable.